# Managing json files on the server with nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, server

Recently, I found that there is called 'LowDB' and it can control the json file with NodeJS.

Actually, I can use MySQL or other databases but I think the App that I developing now is small application so it needs very tiny DB like simple Json.

This Link is connected to lowDB example.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/typicode/4kd7xxbu/)

```
https://github.com/typicode/lowdb
```

As you can see it controls json file and it includes CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) function. But the data are save in Local storage not in server. So Even I control the json files it will only apply in Local Json file. I want to save it in server.
How can I manage json file with NodeJS? Please give me some keywords or introduce some Node Dependencies.

Comment: Check out mongodb. You can use mongoose connector for CRUD operations.

Comment: @EdwinBabu Thanks for the help. I will search about it.